# Cast character to int in order to query properly

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I need to select a range of values (eg : "1", "2", "2A", "3", ...) in a column but these are character varying so I must cast them to int in order to get a proper "BETWEEN" evaluation.

This is what I tried but it seems it ignores the cast, returning only values corresponding to numins = 1001 :

```
SELECT sum(totalchiefs) AS totalchiefs
     , sum(totalnochiefs) AS totalnochiefs
     , sum(totalchildrens) AS totalchildrens
     , sum(totalpeople) AS totalpeople
FROM nombrehabs
WHERE numins = 1001 AND ((numpol~E'^\\d+$')::integer BETWEEN 1 AND 27);
```

Comment: `~` matches a value against a regular expression. So the result of that operator is either `true` or `false` - casting that to an integer returns `0` or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `substring` function to extract the number from your strings.

```
SELECT 
    SUM( totalchiefs ) AS totalchiefs,
    SUM ( totalnochiefs ) AS totalnochiefs,
    SUM ( totalchildrens ) AS totalchildrens,
    SUM ( totalpeople ) AS totalpeople 
FROM
    nombrehabs 
WHERE
    numins = 1001 
    AND (SUBSTRING(numpol FROM '\d+')  :: INTEGER BETWEEN 1 AND 27)
);
```

Checkout the documentation at [9.7. Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html)